# How to draw diagrams of category theory?

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to draw a commutative diagram?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2324/how-to-draw-a-commutative-diagram)

Some times when we want to describe diagrams in category theory such as $$\xymatrix{
U \ar@/_/[ddr]_y \ar@/^/[drr]^x
\ar@{.>}[dr]|-{(x,y)}
\\
& X \times_Z Y \ar[d]^q \ar[r]_p
& X \ar[d]_f
\\
& Y \ar[r]^g
& Z
}$$, we are used to use xypic package. However, it is not available now. So is there another way to draw diagrams?

Comment: This has already been asked and answered on [this meta.math.SE post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2324/264).

Comment: Not a very nice solution, but you could also make the commutative diagram on you computer, convert it with dvipng or [something similar](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11866/compile-a-latex-document-into-a-png-image-thats-as-short-as-possible) and upload the image.

Comment: OK, I see. Thank you two. But I still recommend to add a package since in comment it does not allow us to add a image, and the limit of characters probably restrict us to draw a huge diagram.

Comment: @Popopo: I don't think "adding the package" is something that can be done at the math.SE, or even the StackExchange level: that would be something to bring up with the MathJax folks, if I'm not mistaken.