# How to type this diagram on math.stackexchange?

Tags: support, mathjax, typesetting

Is there a way to type this diagram on math.stackexchange?

[image]

from

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2f/Lifting_diagram.png

For example, I know there is a way to type CD commutative diagram like this:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
SL(2,R)\times S^1 & \longrightarrow & S^1\\
\downarrow               &~&           \downarrow\\
PSL(2,R)\times RP^1 & \longrightarrow &RP^1
\end{array}
$$

Thanks!

Comment: The `array` environment lets one do [a primitive triangle](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2325/3111).  The main drawback is an inability to *label* the diagonal arrows (produced by `\nearrow` and `\searrow`).

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to draw a diagonal arrow in a commutative diagram?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14986) You can also check this post: [Challenge: can you draw the following triangular diagram?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27590) Similar post on MathOverflow Meta: [Triangle commutative diagram does not work here at MO](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4072).

Comment: \nearrow and \searrow help! thanks

Comment: I’ll note that in the ‘challenge’ post Martin linked to, a developer of MathJax (Davide Cervone) resorts to a ‘hack’. So outside of an update I would guess that’s the best option