# Drawing commutative diagrams

Tags: support, mathjax

I am reading category theory and in order to post my questions I need to make commutative diagrams. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2324/how-to-draw-a-commutative-diagram) is a question with useful answers already available.

However I would like to use the DCPic package instead of AMScd. Is it possible to do so ?

Note : I have never used DCPic or any other package previously in latex or on this site and am considering DCPic as [this site](http://jmilne.org/not/CDGuide.html) has a comparision of various packages and DCPic looks the best. 
Any other related advice is welcome. 
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Short answer: no. Longer answer: if you want it you need to convince the [mathJax](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/mathjax.html) team to support it. Workaround answer: have you tried making your pictures on your computer separately and uploading it as an image?

Comment: Please note that this site is not running any sort of TeX. MathJAX is a javascript library which emulate some TeX commands. You cannot simply add a package. Instead, it need someone actually write an emulator for that package.

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks for the help. I did not know that making pictures on my computer and uploading them is an acceptable practice at mse.

Comment: To add to @WillieWong's comment. While one wouldn't technically have to convince the MathJax team -- [third party extension](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-third-party-extensions) are possible -- one would still have to convince Stackexchange to use an extension. E.g., [xyjax](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-third-party-extensions/tree/master/xyjax) weighs in at 305KB, a possibly prohibitive size. One technical problem is that MathJax internally uses MathML, which limits the possible constructs (e.g., no easy way to do diagonal arrows; though xyjax works around this by mixing in SVG).