# Challenge: can you draw the following triangular diagram?

Tags: support, mathjax

I've been struggling to draw the following triangular diagram:

[image]

Can I do it in SE or should I forget about it?

Ideally the line for $f'$ should be dashed.

Comment: I don't think you can make a diagonal arrow in a commutative diagram using Mathjax.  [See here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2324/how-to-draw-a-commutative-diagram?rq=1).  The best alternative I know of is to make the diagram on your computer, save it as an image and then upload it.  [There was also a meta thread not too long ago about TikZ support for the site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26652/can-we-support-tikz-picture-rendering), but it doesn't seem to have gained much traction.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a MathJax version that works, though it is certainly a hack, and only works well with the MathJax TeX fonts, not the STIX fonts, so some people might see a less satisfactory version.

```
$$\require{AMScd}
\def\diaguparrow#1{\smash{\raise.6em\rlap{\scriptstyle #1}
   \lower.3em{\mathord{\diagup}}\raise.52em{\!\mathord{\nearrow}}}}
\begin{CD}
&& X'\\
& \diaguparrow{f'} @VVpV \\
Y @>>f> X
\end{CD}$$
```

which displays as

$$
\require{AMScd}
\def\diaguparrow#1{\smash{\raise.6em\rlap{\scriptstyle #1} \lower.3em{\mathord{\diagup}}\raise.512em{\!\mathord{\nearrow}}}}
\begin{CD}
 && X'\\
 & \diaguparrow{f'} @VVpV \\
Y @>>f> X
\end{CD}
$$

Alternatively, you could use

```
$$\require{AMScd}
\require{cancel}
\def\diaguparrow#1{\smash{\raise.6em\rlap{\ \ \scriptstyle #1}
   \lower.6em{\cancelto{}{\Space{2em}{1.7em}{0px}}}}}
\begin{CD}
&& X'\\
& \diaguparrow{f'} @VVpV \\
Y @>>f> X
\end{CD}$$
```

which produces

$$
\require{AMScd}
\require{cancel}
\def\diaguparrow#1{\smash{\raise.6em\rlap{\ \ \scriptstyle #1}
   \lower.6em{\cancelto{}{\Space{2em}{1.7em}{0px}}}}}
\begin{CD}
 && X'\\
 & \diaguparrow{f'} @VVpV \\
Y @>>f> X
\end{CD}
$$

One could probably adjust the size of the `\Space` command and the `\ \` to improve the result, but I just put this together as an example.

Comment: copy pasting your second code in SE gives "Unknown environment 'CD'" . This is expected?

Comment: Did you enclose the example code in math delimiters, like `$$`?  I have added them to the code examples above, but originally only listed the TeX code.

Comment: There was a recent question on MathOverflow Meta where a user eventually used your diagram but then they also [asked whether the diagonal arrow can be made dotted](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4072/triangle-commutative-diagram-does-not-work-here-at-mo#comment18175_4073).

Comment: @MartinSleziak, yes, I saw that, and your response. I don't have a good solution for dotted or dashed arrows.  The diagonal one I did was just a hack, and I don't see a reasonable way to do it with dashes or dots.

Comment: Thanks for the response. (I have added a comment directing the OP to what you said here.)

Comment: Which command controls the arrow pointing to the upper right? What if I want an arrow pointing to lower right?

Comment: @AGlearner, the `\cancelto{}` command is what creates the arrow here.  Unfortunately, there is not a corresponding one for a downward arrow.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested [in this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2324/how-to-draw-a-commutative-diagram/12372#12372), one option is to use presheaf and include the image. On this website you can use xypic syntax. (Of course, you can do the same if you have LaTeX - including xy package - on your computer and can convert the result to a picture. Either solution - doing it online and doing it locally - has some advantages and some disadvantages.)

```
&X' \ar[d]^p\\
Y \ar[ru]^{f'} \ar[r]_f& X
```

http://presheaf.com/?d=d2bz1i6f6m4w2s3r5e4w6x44443f1h3l

[image: diagram]

> Ideally the line for $f′$ should be dashed.

This is obtained in xypic by modifier `@{-->}`

```
&X' \ar[d]^p\\
Y \ar@{-->}[ru]^{f'} \ar[r]_f& X
```

http://presheaf.com/?d=d68725l1w6m5r4k6l3s3j45y1i6x6y57

[image: diagram]