# need help on how to re-post an existing question that contains too many questions

Tags: support, images

I want to repost part of my question: [Questions concerning quotient spaces specifically collapsing a set to a point.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3457833/questions-concerning-quotient-spaces-specifically-collapsing-a-set-to-a-point)

One of the commenter stated that I have included like ten questions in a single post.  I want to break up the questions into groups and also, since the question mainly have to with visualising quotient spaces, I would like to ask what I can use for including simple illustrations.  Do I go with the route that require me to learn more latex.  Also, how do I insert illustration underneath each question instead of being in a separate places within the post.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can add images, but it's discouraged by most ( partially because of screenreaders, partially because an asker is unlikely to be able to describe the image well enough, partially because We have MathJaX for basic diagrams).

Comment: You have included three questions in a single post.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee how do I create diagrams with MathJax?

Comment: plenty on meta about that key term commutative diagram.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30580/what-are-your-options-to-draw-commutative-diagrams-on-mse/30582#30582 for example

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee can it also show how an interval on $\mathbb{R}$ collapses to a point.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology) top of the page ...

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee if I have an interval ((a,b),[a,b], or [a,b)) and I declare every element in that interval to be equivalent in the sense of being an equivalence class, that interval is not a circle.  It just becomes a point or a single element.

Comment: To see what people use to created pictures (for the purposes of posts on [math.se] and also for other purposes), you can check this post on meta: [Creating diagrams](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9632). And in the comments you can find links to some other posts concerning this topic.