# How can we draw kernel diagram in the Math Stackexchange?

Tags: support, mathjax

I don't know I can ask this kind of question here. Anyway, I propose a question.

How can we draw next type commutative diagram

[image]

? My scope of ability of drawing commutative diagram is for example as follows :

1. I can draw next kind of diagram : $$\require{AMScd}
   \begin{CD}
   K(X) @>{ch}>> H(X;\mathbb Q);\\
   @VVV @VVV \\
   K(Y) @>{ch}>> H(Y;\mathbb Q);
   \end{CD}$$

2. I also can draw next kind of diagram :

\begin{CD} A @>f>> B\\ @.     {_{\rlap{\ g\circ f}}\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(30deg)}{{\xrightarrow[\rule{4em}{0em}]{}}}} @VVgV\\  @. D \end{CD}

But I don't know how can I draw the above diagram. How can we draw the left-right triangle of such shape? How can we draw dashed arrow?

Can anyone helps?

First attempt : As attempt, I wrote a code trying to draw the above diagram.

$$\require{AMScd}
\require{cancel}
\def\diaguparrow#1{\smash{\raise.6em\rlap{\ \ \scriptstyle #1}
   \lower.6em{\cancelto{}{\Space{2em}{1.7em}{0px}}}}}
\begin{CD}
&& X'\\
& \swarrow{f'} @VVpV \searrow{h}\\
Y @>>f> X @>>g >Z
\end{CD}$$

My question is,

1. How can we draw the dashed arrow ?
2. How can we draw 'long' diagonal arrow ?

Comment: Just for reference, there is this question: [How to draw a commutative diagram?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2324) And [other questions linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/2324) seem to be related. I don't remember a satisfactory solution for diagonal arrows. Still, you might have a look at this question: [Challenge: can you draw the following triangular diagram?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27590) (Personally I would probably embed a picture if I needed such diagram. I used to add a link to presheaf - but the site no longer works.)