# How to draw a diamond shaped commutative diagram using MathJax?

Tags: support, mathjax

I have seen the answer to [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2324/how-to-draw-a-commutative-diagram) question. However there it only shows how to draw square shaped commutative diagrams. Can someone tell me how to draw a diamond shaped one? That is how can I draw one that is rotated by $45$ degrees?

Thank you.

Comment: [Presheaf](http://presheaf.com/), which was mentioned in [this answrer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/12372) could serve as a workaround for things which cannot be done in MathJax.

Comment: @MartinSleziak, thank you. I did not notice that last answer. This is what I am looking for.