# How to draw a commutative diagram on math.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, mathjax

I want to draw a rectangle commutative diagram, but I do not know how. 
The MathJax codes I find on the internet do not work here. 
I tried the following:

```
$\xymatrix
\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}\ar[r]^{\theta_{n+1,\alpha}} \ar[d]  U_1/U_{n+1}\ar[d]  \\
\mathbb{Z}/p^{n-1}\mathbb{Z} \ar[r]^{\theta_{n,\alpha}}  \\ 
U_1/U_n 
$
```

Comment: Older question: [How to draw a commutative diagram?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2324) (You can find there link to the presheaf site. If you are used to xypic syntax, a possibility is to use that website and include the picture in the post.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The package you want to use is not supported on this site, sorry. 
You could use AMScd instead:

```
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z} @>{\theta_{n+1,\alpha}}>> U_1/U_{n+1}\\
@VVV @VVV\\
\mathbb{Z}/p^{n-1}\mathbb{Z} @>{\theta_{n,\alpha}}>> U_1/U_n
\end{CD}
```

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z} @>{\theta_{n+1,\alpha}}>> U_1/U_{n+1}\\
@VVV @VVV\\
\mathbb{Z}/p^{n-1}\mathbb{Z} @>{\theta_{n,\alpha}}>> U_1/U_n
\end{CD}

I hope I got it right; I just read your source and my brain is not the most reliable compiler.

For some more details see [the relevant answer in the main MathJax thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16888/).

Comment: Thank you. You got it right!

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad to know it worked out.