# How do you typeset Dynkin-like diagrams with MathJax?

Tags: support, mathjax

I just [posted a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2760546/167197) where I  typeset the $E_6$, $E_7$, and $E_8$ Dynkin diagrams using MathJax. It looks alright to me, by I'm worried the alignment will look off to users viewing the post with a different browser, or with different default fonts installed, etc. Is there a more reliable way to typeset the Dynkin diagrams with MathJax to guarantee that everything is aligned well regardless of browser settings?

Or to broaden this question, what is the most reliable way to typeset Dynkin-like diagrams in MathJax on this website, like the [Satake diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satake_diagram), or the [affine Dynkin diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_diagram#Affine_Dynkin_diagrams)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the Dynkin diagrams for anyone who would like to use them. To see the MathJax source for them, right-click on the Dynkin diagrams below, select `Show Math As`, then `TeX Commands`.

$$
A_n\; 
\begin{aligned}
  \circ\!-\!\circ\!-\dotsb-\!\circ 
\end{aligned}
\qquad\quad
D_n\; 
\begin{aligned}
  &\>\circ \\[-1ex]
  &\,\,\mid \\[-1ex]
  \circ\,\!-\!&\circ\!-\!\circ\!-\dotsb-\!\circ 
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
E_6\; 
\begin{aligned}
  &\>\circ \\[-1ex]
  &\,\,\mid \\[-1ex]
  \circ\!-\!\circ\!-\!&\circ\!-\!\circ\!-\!\circ 
\end{aligned}
\qquad
E_7\;
\begin{aligned}
  &\>\circ \\[-1ex]
  &\,\,\mid \\[-1ex]
  \circ\!-\!\circ\!-\!&\circ\!-\!\circ\!-\!\circ\!-\!\circ
\end{aligned}
\qquad
E_8\;
\begin{aligned}
  &\>\circ \\[-1ex]
  &\,\,\mid \\[-1ex]
  \circ\!-\!\circ\!-\!&\circ\!-\!\circ\!-\!\circ\!-\!\circ\!-\!\circ 
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
B_n\; 
\begin{aligned}
  \circ=\!\!\Leftarrow\circ\!-\dotsb-\!\circ 
\end{aligned}
\qquad\quad
C_n\; 
\begin{aligned}
  \circ\Rightarrow\!\!=&\circ\!-\!\circ\!-\dotsb-\!\circ 
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
F_4\; 
\begin{aligned}
  \circ\!-\!\circ\Rightarrow\!\!=\circ\!-\!\circ 
\end{aligned}
\qquad\quad
G_2\; 
\begin{aligned}
  \circ\Rrightarrow\!\!\equiv&\circ 
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, here are the [Coxeter-Dynkin diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter%E2%80%93Dynkin_diagram) that are not Dynkin diagrams (I also include alternate presentations for $B_n=C_n={BC}_n$, $F_4$ and $G_2$ that are usual in this context).

$$I_p\; 
\begin{aligned}
  \circ\!\overset{p}{-}\!\circ
\end{aligned}
\qquad\quad
H_3\; 
\begin{aligned}
  \circ\!\overset{5}{-}\!\circ\!-\!\circ 
\end{aligned}
\qquad\quad
H_4\; 
\begin{aligned}
  \circ\!\overset{5}{-}\!\circ\!-\!\circ\!-\!\circ 
\end{aligned}$$

$$
{BC}_n\; 
\begin{aligned}
  \circ\!\overset{4}{-}\!\circ\!-\dotsb-\!\circ 
\end{aligned}
\qquad\quad
F_4\; 
\begin{aligned}
  \circ\!-\!\circ\!\overset{4}{-}\!\circ\!-\!\circ 
\end{aligned}
\qquad\quad
G_2\; 
\begin{aligned}
  \circ\!\overset{6}{-}\!\circ
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Since I had to make them anyways here are images of the Dynkin diagrams using the [technique here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31041/167197) and the `dynkin-diagrams` LaTeX package.

#### PNG of ADE diagrams with transparent background

[image]

#### PNG of BCFG diagrams with transparent background

[image]