# How to draw Coxeter-Dynkin diagrams?

Tags: discussion

I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3549400/480135) on the main site. There was an answer, and I edited the question to be more accurate about what I'm asking.

Meanwhile, I did some searching on Wikipedia, and found "[5-cell honeycomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5-cell_honeycomb)." I guess this is what I was looking for, yet being an undergraduate student, I can't prove it.

I presume if anyone posts another answer, it's going to involve Coxeter-Dynkin diagrams. Is there any way to draw Coxeter-Dynkin diagrams here?

Comment: A bit related: [How do you typeset Dynkin diagrams with MathJax?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28336)

Comment: @XanderHenderson Partially. Coxeter-Dynkin diagrams have variety on their vertices and edges.