# Embedding tikzcd diagrams

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

I know [some tags are not supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites#answer-135909), and some of them will likely never be (I have the `<table>` tag in mind). However, it is sometimes useful to embbed commutative diagrams in some question/answers. Currently, the "[life hack](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2325/259363)" that does not require third-party tools is somewhat dirty, and the [beautiful approach](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/31041/259363) uses 1) compiling a document, 2) cropping a screen capture, and 3) uploading it.

Hoever, [Yichuan Shen](https://yichuanshen.de/) has a very convenient tool, [tikzcd-editor](https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/) $-$ that I even use when I'm writing TeX documents $-$, is on tracks to being a quick solution to this problem. There are still two downsides :

1. It still requires a screen capture and cropping an image (at least, it saves the TeX standalone compiling).
2. This tool uses guidelines to help creating diagrams, which are going to be displayed on any screen capture.

I know that `<iframe>` tags are not part of the list of allowed tags. However, I was wondering if it were possible to embed such diagrams directly onto a question/answer. What I have in mind is the possibility to generate a UID for each `tikzcd-editor` diagram. For instance, for [this](https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/#N4Igdg9gJgpgziAXAbVABwnAlgFyxMJZABgBpiBdUkANwEMAbAVxiRAEUQBfU9TXfIRQBGUsKq1GLNgAVuvEBmx4CRAExiJ9Zq0QgAmvL7LBRUWq1TdIABpHF-FUOQaL1bdL0AtbhJhQAc3giUAAzACcIAFskABZqHAgkAGZ3KzZQ+wjouISkxA1JHTYAkGoGOgAjGAYZR1M9cKwAgAscLMiYgrykUSLPEAAdQawouhwWgH01MpAK6tr61Ubmto6cxFSQRN604r1h0fGp4XWurZ3EMhBqsCgU649rYYArMYnJ054wzqRCy+ut3uiAAtMlHukDoM3sdprN5jU6iZliAmq12t8QNkun0AeUsGBrFA6HAWv5Zk82MMYAAPLBwHBwACE8KqiKWQjmMFCGIoXCAA) pushout diagram, the UID generated is :

```
N4Igdg9gJgpgziAXAbVABwnAlgFyxMJZABgBpiBdUkANwEMAbAVxiRAEUQBfU9TXfIRQBGUsKq1GLNgAVuvEBmx4CRAExiJ9Zq0QgAmvL7LBRUWq1TdIABpHF-FUOQaL1bdL0AtbhJhQAc3giUAAzACcIAFskABZqHAgkAGZ3KzZQ+wjouISkxA1JHTYAkGoGOgAjGAYZR1M9cKwAgAscLMiYgrykUSLPEAAdQawouhwWgH01MpAK6tr61Ubmto6cxFSQRN604r1h0fGp4XWurZ3EMhBqsCgU649rYYArMYnJ054wzqRCy+ut3uiAAtMlHukDoM3sdprN5jU6iZliAmq12t8QNkun0AeUsGBrFA6HAWv5Zk82MMYAAPLBwHBwACE8KqiKWQjmMFCGIoXCAA
```

Then, it would be convenient to just generate the code, as I did, and to somehow embbed it in a question, that would include it somehow. In my example, it would simply produce (I am just uploading an image, for the sake of illustrating my question) :

[image: Pushout]

The embedding would get rid of the guidelines and do all the "hard-work" for us. Is that possible ? Also, is my question welcome ? I know this has been asked [quite](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32532/can-i-make-this-little-table-of-diagrams-better-than-ascii-graphics) [a](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9632/creating-diagrams) [few](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29325/software-to-draw-geometrical-diagrams) [times](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28336/how-do-you-typeset-dynkin-like-diagrams-with-mathjax), but I have the feeling my approach is different and somehow deserves a question on its own. The thing is : are suggestions like mine allowed ? (Sorry for being new to the Meta community !)

Comment: Welcome to Meta Math.SE!  With feature requests I think it is useful to consider how the proposal affects the software developers as well as the user community, so that the trade-off can be judge in terms of the benefit achieved by the amount of effort required.

Comment: +1 This would be great and save a lot of time. Yichuan Shen's tool is very efficient. I sometimes don't write a post, because I can't be bother to copy-paste multiple diagrams (especially if you want to edit something, you need to do it all over).