# Equivalent of `@VVV` for uparrow in commutative diagram?

Tags: support, mathjax

Following questions [like this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2324/746312), I managed to draw a commutative diagram like below using package `AMScd`:

$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
X @>>> X \\
@V{f}VV @V{f^{-1}}VV \uparrow \\
X @>>> X \\
\end{CD}$$

```
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
X @>>> X \\
@V{f}VV @V{f^{-1}}VV \uparrow \\
X @>>> X \\
\end{CD}$$
```

However, none of the answers shows an arrow that's vertically up, and `\uparrow` is to short (see diagram).  So what's the analog of `@VVV` for upwards pointing arrow? `@VVV` is particularly nice because you can add labels at different positions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `A` rather than `V` (or `AAA` rather than `VVV`) seems to be working:

```
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
X @>>> X \\
@A{f}AA @A{f^{-1}}AA  \\
X @>>> X \\
\end{CD}$$
```

$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
X @>>> X \\
@A{f}AA @A{f^{-1}}AA  \\
X @>>> X \\
\end{CD}$$

I will mention that the syntax here should be the same (or at least similar) as in the amscd package. The documentation for this package can be [found in various places](https://www.google.com/search?q=latex+amscd).